# Wearing a Tallis for Aliyah at Chabad

Tags: torah-service, tallit-gadol

If there is someone who is not married. However, when he gets an Aliyah he usually wears a tallis (follows Ashkenazi Minhagim), should he wear one if called up for an Aliyah at a Chabad where the custom is to never wear a Tallis before marriage or for Aliyah’s in general?

Comment: מנהג המקוםis the rule. ואל ישנה אדם, מפני המחלקות.

Comment: Related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/35568/759

Comment: I'm a bit confused.  Is the hypothetical man married?  You say he is but then you imply he might not be since the Chabad rule is for single men not to wear tallitot.

Comment: I meant to add for mincha. And in the case of shachris an unmarried man.

Comment: This just happened to me this shabbos. Were you there? ;-) I asked for a Tallis and they gave me one. Most likely it was to be nice. I didn't even notice that I was doing something unusual for them

Comment: No one at a chabad house is gonna try to stop you from wearing a Tallis for an aliya if it is your minhag to do so

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should follow your own minhag.

That is to comply with the requirement of *not abandoning the Torah of your Mother* like is found in the She'iltot d'Rav Achai Gaon 67:2, Tur Orach Chaim 455:1, Chayei Adam, Shabbat and Festivals 127:1, Kol Bo 48:110.

This is also the view of Chabad as explained by the Lubavitcher Rebbe himself in Torat Menachem Hitvadiyut, Vol.8, pp.31-32, beginning with the words, "משתדלים לקיים ולחזק את המנהגים העתיקים".

Comment: That may be Chabad's view. However, I don't think this is universal. If anything, I've seen that you should follow the shul's minhag. Several shuls I've attended won't give an aliyah unless you wear a hat. In some cases, they will slap someone else's hat on your head when you come up. In another place, you had to wear a tie. (I can't figure out why that place didn't keep spare ties around, though.)

Comment: To my knowledge, the types of things you are describing are not minhagim. They are particular takkanot of a specific synagogue. It's not the same thing.

Comment: How do you know this is chabad’s view?

Comment: @mroll I’ve heard the subject from the mouth of two different very prominent Lubavitcher poskim.

Comment: @DanF Just to put it in perspective, you do not have to take an aliyah when they offer. A polite, no thank you, would avoid any hint of conflict. But I have never had contact with or heard of a Chabad shul that would insist that someone, in particular a guest either remove or put on a tallit gadol for an aliyah. They might offer, but that is simply courtesy.

Comment: My cousin doesn't immediately refuse an aliyah when he is a guest in a shul. Before accepting or declining, he asks, "How much will this cost?"

Comment: @DanF, at KAJ, one of the gabbayim keeps spare ties in his shtender. He also lends out his hat (rather than some random guy's hat)